# Gatling : How to double the number of users after specific interval?

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, stress-testing

Right now I'm injecting users like this, which will gradually increase the number of users over the period of 30 minutes:

```
setUp(
       users.inject(rampUsers(300) over ((30) minutes))
   ).protocols(httpConf)
```

What I want is during the duration of 1st and 10th minute inject the 300 users, during the duration of  11th and 20th minute inject 300 more users which will be 300 + 300 = 600 and during the duration of 21st and 30th minute inject 300 more users which will be 300 + 300 + 300 = 900. In short, I want to double the number of users after every 10 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you want 10 minutes where there are 300 users followed by 10 min where there are 600, and finally another 10 where there are 900.

You could used one of the closed injection profiles to achieve this.

```
scn.inject(
  constantConcurrentUsers(300) during (10 minutes),
  constantConcurrentUsers(600) during (10 minutes),
  constantConcurrentUsers(900) during (10 minutes)
)
```

Comment: can we run this some how in loop, instead of creating three seperate commands ?

Comment: .inject just takes an array of injection steps, so it's pretty straightforward to generate that. eg: `(300 to 900 by 300).map(i => constantConcurrentUsers(i) during (10 minutes))` would work

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate those commands:

```
scn.inject(
    rampUsers(300) during (10 minutes),
    rampUsers(300) during (10 minutes),
    rampUsers(300) during (10 minutes),
)
```

Like the documentation says:

> The definition of the injection profile of users is done with the inject method. This method takes as argument a sequence of injection steps that will be processed sequentially. (https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/general/simulation_setup)

Also, the behavior you described could be achieved by just doing `rampUsers(900) during (30 minutes)`.

Comment: Don't you think this will inject users in parallel ? I want to inject 300 users during first 10 minutes, during second 10+10=20 minutes inject another group of 300 users, in total 600 users and during the third 10+10+10=30 minutes inject another 300 users, in total 900 users in the end.

Comment: this depends entirely on what your scenario does and how long it takes to run. The close model injection steps (like rampUsers) just starts a user executing a scenario. If you have some kind of loop or 'forever' in your scenario, then could still be running into the 3rd 10 minute block. If you don't have looping in your scenario, then you could use the 'constantConcurrentUsers' injection profile to get what you're after.